# how to retrieve rows from dataframe 1 that matches condition with dataframe 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`df1` dataframe has `'A'` column.
`df2` dataframe has `'B'` and `'index'` column.
I want to know how to retrieve `df2`'s `'index'` values
from rows that match `'A'` value of `df1` with `'B'` value of `df2`.
How can I do this using pandas methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `merge`

```
merge_df = df1.merge(df2, left_on='A', right_on'B')
```

And then, get the `index` values as a list by using

```
merge_df['index'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': ['toto', 'thomas','marine'], 'ok': [3, 4,5]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

d = {'B': ['toto', 'marine','paul'], 'index': ['oui', 'non',"jsp"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2.loc[df2['B'].isin(df1['A']),'index'].to_list()
```